# typescript definition libraries for rendering dynamic meta data

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-2017

I have a web app developed in reactjs using typescript in which one of its component is user profile. Now the state for this user profile page gets assigned by an api call on the client side. This state is also used to assign some of the contents of the meta tags. I have used helmet for this purpose. But it does not work if the meta tags are going to be dynamically rendered. I have a dynamic url(www.MySPA.com/{username}) and whenever I share this url the meta tags shall get rendered. Can anybody suggest me some typescript definition libraries which i can use in my react web app to achieve this?

**Note:** I have already tried prerender, react-meta-tags, prerender.io, snapshot, etc but no typescript definitions are available for this libraries